# Can send emails through Gmail account only if account has "Access for less secure apps" enabled

Tags: authentication, gmail, smtpclient, asp.net-identity-2

If my *Gmail account* has **Access for less secure apps** *disabled*, then my application can't send *emails* through this *account*. Instead I get "*The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required*" exception.

[Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) Google explains that by *disabling* **Access for less secure apps**, only apps that use *modern security standards* can *sign in*.

What are those *modern security standards* my code needs to implement and can you show me how to implement them with an example ( not sure if it matters, but my *app* and *Gmail account* aren't using *2-step verification* )?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var credentialUserName = "myAccount@gmail.com";
        var sentFrom = "myAccount@gmail.com";
        var pwd = "myPwd";

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = 
            new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = 
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentialUserName, pwd);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        var mail = 
            new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: They switched over to OAuth 2.0. Anything else is "less secure" to them.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple GMail accounts, and you follow the link to enable access for less secure apps from the GMail app on a mobile device, make sure you are updating the settings for the intended account.  If you do not receive an e-mail stating that access for less secure apps is enabled, double-check the settings and ensure it has been applied to the intended account.

Comment: Just about to ask this question. Thanks. +1

Comment: If it helps, I have an old phone where, when I try accessing gmail, it say incorrect password, and later, on my PC, I get an email from Google saying "Access from a device we don't consider safe was stopped"..

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the *asp.net-identity-2* tag is applied to this question, and considering that Google requires use of *OAuth 2.0* to avoid having to use the *Access for less secure applications* option, it appears that one option is to use the [OWIN middleware](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana) able to be found by searching for the term *Oauth 2.0* at [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/search).

This site hosts an [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) titled *Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on* that might be of some interest.  The article appears to show many screenshots that walk a developer through the process of getting the resource, creating an app, and authenticating with a *Google* server.

Answer (score 0):

I think it **"Less secure"** only means that **you are giving credentials to third party and they do not use two step verification**.

> **About Google "Less Secure" Settings**
>
> It should be noted that Google's statement of Less Secure should not
> be read as Insecure. Less Secure Apps is a label describing a
> behavioral issue and not a technical issue. Lots of things can go
> wrong when you give your credentials to a third party to give to the
> authentication authority: the third party might keep the credentials
> in storage without telling you, they might use your credentials for
> purposes outside the stated scope of the application, they might send
> your credentials over a network without encryption, etc. Ultimately,
> it is only Less Secure if the third party in question has malicious
> intent and therefore you should always be vigilant in knowing who you
> are sending your credentials to. COMPanion Corp stores your
> credentials only for the purpose of utilizing Googles SMTP Email
> service and they are stored using the most up-to-date security.

Source: http://www.goalexandria.com/v7Docs/index.php/Using_Gmail_as_Your_SMTP_Server